# C++ replace toString with an overloaded output operator

Tags: c++, class, operators, operator-overloading

So i need to replace the formatted output method (toString) with an overloaded output/insertion operator, and modify the driver to use the overloaded operator.

```
string Movie::toString() const {
ostringstream oS;
oS << "\n\n====================== Movie Information\n"
<< "\n             Movie Title:\t" << title << "  (" << releaseYear << ")"
<< "\n    US Rank & Box Office:\t" << usRank << "\t$" << usBoxOffice
<< "\nNon-US Rank & Box Office:\t" << nonUSRank << "\t$" << nonUSBoxOffice
<< "\n World Rank & Box Office:\t" << worldRank << "\t$" << worldBoxOffice
<< "\n";
return oS.str();
}
```

And i did this

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Movie movie)
{
os << "\n\n====================== Movie Information\n"
<< "\n             Movie Title:\t" << movie.getTitle()
<< "  (" << movie.getReleaseYear() << ")  " << movie.getStudio()
<< "\n    US Rank & Box Office:\t" <<  movie.getUSRank() << "\t$" <<  movie.getUSBoxOffice()
<< "\nNon-US Rank & Box Office:\t" <<  movie.getNonUSRank() << "\t$" <<  movie.getNonUSBoxOffice()
<< "\n World Rank & Box Office:\t" <<  movie.getWorldRank()<< "\t$" <<  movie.getWorldBoxOffice()
<< "\n";
return os;
}
}
```

But now i have to access this function from my main (instead of toString), how do I do that??

```
const Movie * m;
if(m != nullptr)
{
    cout<< m->toString();
    if(m->getWorldBoxOffice() > 0)
    {
        //cout << setprecision(1) << fixed;
        cout <<"\n\t US to World Ratio:\t" << (m->getUSBoxOffice()*100.0) / m->getWorldBoxOffice() << "%\n" << endl;
    }
    else cout << "Zero World Box Office\n";
}
```

Comment: Pass by const reference: Use `const Movie& movie` (note the **`&`**).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout << *m` should do the trick. Your `operator <<` is incorrect though. It should be a `friend function`.

```
class Movie {
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Movie &movie);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Movie &movie) { ..... }
```

Comment: it says "no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are std::ostream << const Movie"

Comment: @user3314023, If I helped, you can help everyone else by accepting the answer

Comment: His operator<< is *not* incorrect. It only has to be a friend when it has to access private data members. Don't teach him that he *always* has to use a friend operator because that's not always the case.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm pretty sure he defined it _in_ the class itself, which is why I said it was incorrect. But you are right about it not always needing to be a friend.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that he attempted to define it inside the class? If he had done that he would've gotten a compilation error but he doesn't complain about anything like that...

Comment: @0x499602D2 not very clear, but he did say this (top comment)  "no operator "<<" matches these operands operand types are std::ostream << const Movie"... which is what happens if you mess up in VS 2013

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
cout << m->toString();
```

with:

```
cout << *m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like so:

```
cout << *m;
```

I.e. you have to remove the `->toString();` and also reference `m`(using `*`).